# Why does the void operator invoke GetValue(expr) when it always evaluates to undefined?

Tags: javascript

[The void operator in JavaScript](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_11.htm#Section_11.4.2) will call the internal `GetValue(expr)`, but always return `undefined`, regardless of what value or expressions are.

The spec says:

> **11.4.2 The void Operator**
>
> The production *UnaryExpression : void UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating *UnaryExpression*.
> 2. Call `GetValue(expr)`.
> 3. Return undefined.
>
> GetValue must be called even though its value is not used because it may have observable side-effects.

My question is, why? What sort of observable side-effects could happen? Can we demonstrate how void might alter program flow, and discuss what would happen if we didn't run `GetValue`?

Comment: None of the answers here seem to explain `Call GetValue(expr).`, where `expr` is the **result** of *UnaryExpression*. It's specifically step 2 that you seem to be asking about. Is that right.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Correct. Why return something we'll never use? Why use void to return undefined if we have other means to return undefined? (two parts to the question)

Comment: @Incognito: Wait, so you're actually asking for uses of `void`, and not of the potential side effects of the internal `GetValue()`?

Comment: Well, because this is too contrived to really be it's own answer (but an exception is an *observable side-effect* that often alters program flow): `function f() { "lots of stuff, maybe like solving this question and proving some NP theorems"; throw "hello!" }; void f()`. Also, `void x` *evaluates to* the value undefined, always.

Comment: @RightSaidFred No, I'm being confusing. I want to know about the side-effects, but I'm curious why bother with void, for instance, `alert("h1")` as it's own statement doesn't need void, as the returned value never gets used anyway. The bookmarklet answer explained that, but the side-effects part is the main question.

Comment: @Incognito: That's what I thought, and that's the part I'd be curious to know about too. Othwerwise it would seem that the spec could skip `2` by evaluating the *UnaryExpression*, ignoring the return value, and returning `undefined`.

Comment: @pst: But `void x` will also result in an internal `GetValue(x)` *after* the `x` expression has been evaluated. This apparently can have side effects. The question is what are they.

Comment: @RightSaidFred The same as evaluating `x` on it's own :) I like where your last comment was going: evaluation alone is enough to cause all the [potential] the side-effects, unless additional side-effects can be introduced in GetValue...?

Comment: @pst: Yes, that's the odd thing. The example I had under a now deleted answer was `void foo()`, where `foo` returns `"bar"`. Because `"bar"` is the result of the *UnaryExpression*, it is `GetValue("bar")` that has potential for side effects. (Not saying a string will have side effects, but *something* must.) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're writing a program with no side effects, then a function that always returns undefined isn't helpful because it does not return useful information back to the caller.  In that case, you might as well not call the function at all if you always know what you'll be getting back.

However, if a language has "side effects", even functions that return undefined can still be programatically useful.  "Side-effects" is a technical term for some effect that's not a part of the return value of a function.  As a concrete example, mutating the DOM is a side effect that doesn't compute and return a useful value, but you still want the state of your DOM tree to mutate.  Playing a sound is also a side effect.

As a side note, *void* can be useful since, grammatically, it forces an expression context, so that things like function expression values can be expressed unambiguously.  e.g.

```
void function(){alert('hi')}()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this a few times with use cases such as:

```
javascript:void window.open("http://foo.com")
```

This can be used in [bookmarklets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklets) to avoid changing the value on the address bar, but still executing the code - so you would obviously want to evaluate that function and not just ignore it.

It's also sometimes used by paranoid programmers who don't trust that `undefined` was not overridden somewhere.  If you really need to know `undefined`, you can compare it to `void 0` (since `void` is a reserved keyword, it cannot be used as a function name).

Comment: Nit: `void` is an *operator* -- and a reserved word prohibited from being used as a literal identifier.

Comment: I have seen it used a lot in bookmarklets, couldn't we simply avoid use of it by not returning anything via closure or some other means?

Comment: @Incognito - For sure there's other ways, but maybe not as clean.  I think `void` is just a quick way of saying "we want to evaluate this function, however we want the logical value of this expression to be `undefined` for whatever reason"