# Is `if (condition = value)` the correct syntax for comparison?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

If  `if((hit.transform != transform)` means `if hit.transform is Not transform`, then how do I check if the statement Is correct. `if(hit.transform = transform)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks dudes for the Quick and Lots of answers.. StackOverflow is the best!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need two equals signs for equality

```
if (hit.transform == transform)
```

Note that that will allow all sorts of implicit conversions, so you should really use three equals signs—identity equality or strict equality:

```
if (hit.transform === transform)
```

Note that a single equals sign is assignment.

```
x = y;
```

Now x has the value of y.

Your statement

```
if(hit.transform = transform)
```

Assigns hit.transform to the value of transform, then tests to see if the result of this expression, which will be the same as hit.transform's new value, is "truthy"

Comment: Also, `===` is *not* identity-equality. It is strict-equality: the two objects might actually be *different* objects, but still pass the strict-equality test.

Comment: @AdamRackis Right, up in the answer then -- and why is `if(a = b)` "valid"? (Even if it acts funny.) What is it really doing? You're gonna have to work for your up-vote ;-)

Comment: Hello, should he use !== too? or just !=?

Comment: @pst: *"the two objects might actually be different objects, but still pass the strict-equality test"* An example perhaps?

Comment: @AdamRackis I'll take it for +1. However, it is the *resulting value* of the expression `hit.transform = transform` that is passed to the `if` -- at that point variables/properties have nothing else to do with it. Also, "strict equality" ;-)

Comment: @RightSaidFred `"a" + "b" === "ab"` Okay, granted it's not as exciting as it could be...

Comment: @ajax333221 - yes - != allows the same implicit conversions as ==, and !== prohibits these implicit conversions, just like ===

Comment: @pst: But those are primitives, not objects. `(new String("a" + "b")) !== (new String("ab"))`

Comment: AdamRackis: But @pst is right about *"it is the resulting value of the expression"*, though the resulting value will be the same as the assigned value.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Ah, very true. You win on the semantic grounds. I should have said "values" above and been safe ;-) I am not up-to-date with ECMAScript ed5, can the `===` behavior be influenced in that?

Comment: @ Adam thanks for explaining. === doesn't work for me in Unity though, == does. thanks again!

Comment: @RightSaidFred - fair enough.  I edited to be more accurate.  The SO crowd always keeps me honest and precise - I like that

Comment: @pst: Influenced in what way? The `===` does do an identity comparison when it comes to objects. From [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.6) *"Return true if x and y refer to the same object."*

Comment: @Thomas: If `===` doesn't work but `==` does, it would probably be good to examine why that is. The `==` does some crazy stuff.

Comment: @RightSaidFred Thanks for the link. The ed5 specification is so hard to grok sometimes -- I thought it might have passed through GetValue in a way that made it alterable.

Comment: @pst: You're welcome. That reminds me of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331891/why-does-the-void-operator-invoke-getvalueexpr-when-it-always-evaluates-to-und) though. Did we (you) figure out about the way(s) in which `GetValue` may have side effects? I've been too lazy to investigate. :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the requirements, you may choose between `==` and `===` (negated these will become `!=` and `!==` respectively). The triple equal sign notation will also perform type checking.

Try entering the following in your javascript console:

```
1 ==  1    // true
1 === 1    // true

1 ==  "1"  // true
1 === "1"  // false
```

Edit: `=` is the assignment operator, which is different from the above comparator operators:

```
a = 1      // 1
a = "1"    // "1"
a = "foo"  // "foo"
```

When using this within an `if`-condition like `if(a = "foo")` you are effectively setting `a` to `"foo"`, and then testing `if("foo")`. While `"foo"` in itself is not a boolean condition, the Javascript engine will convert it to `true`, which is why it still works.

This is however likely to introduce very subtle bugs which may be quite hard to trace down, so you'd better avoid programming like this unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: So what is up with the `=` in the post? What is going on with it?

Comment: Extended answer to deal with `=`

Answer (score 2):

it's

```
if(hit.transform == transform)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use '==='

Here is the first result on google with an explanation
http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/03/quality-equality-with-javascript-quotquot-gt-quotquot.aspx

Answer (score 1):

- `!=` is **not** equal to.
- `==` is equal to.

So you'd write:

```
if (hit.transform == transform) {
```

What you wrote actually attempts so **set** the value of `hit.transform` to `transform`.

Comment: So what does `=` do and why does it work the way it does (in context)?